# Blazor: Creating a form using partial components

Tags: c#, blazor

### Question

I have a class:

```cs
// Person.cs
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
  public double Temperature { get; set; }
  public double Pulse { get; set; }
  public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a form that reuses partial forms as components, such as this:

```cs
// MyForm.razor
<h1>Currently editing: @Person.Name</h1>
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext">
  <PersonDefault />
  <PersonHealthStats />
</EditContext>
@code {
  private Person Person;
  private EditContext? EditContext;
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    EditContext = new(Person);
  }
}
```

How would I go about creating these partial components?

### Requirements

1. The `PersonDefault` component should include inputs for the `Name` and `DateOfBirth` fields.
2. The `PersonHealthStats` component should include inputs for the `Temperature`, `Pulse`, and `Weight` fields.
3. When a field is updated, it should update `Person`
4. When the `Name` field is updated, it should sync with the h1 tag.

### What I've Tried

**1. Binding `Person` to the child component**

```cs
// MyForm.razor
<PersonDefault @bind-Person="Person" />

// PersonDefault.razor
<input @bind="Person.Name" />
@code {
  [Parameter] public Person Person { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public EventCallback<Person> PersonChanged { get; set; }
}
```

This solution works for updating the values on `Person`, but doesn't sync with the h1 tag.

**2. Binding individual parameters for each field**

```cs
// MyForm.razor
<PersonDefault @bind-Name="Person.Name" />

// PersonDefault.razor
<input @bind="Name" />
@code {
  [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> NameChanged { get; set; }
  private string _Name;

  [Parameter] public string Name {
    get => _Name;
    set
    {
      if (_Name == value) return;
      _Name = value;
      NameChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
  }
}
```

This solution works for updating the values on `Person` and syncing the h1 tag, but creates a lot of redundant code the more input fields I add to the component.

**EDIT:**

I made an image  to better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: I've seen your answer but why do you want to split the form into different components?  Why not one form?  How are you going to validate your data?  How do you save/update the data?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I'm fairly new to Blazor and I'm trying to recreate something our system already does. Personally, I think one form would make more sense, but that's not our current functionality. As for validation, from what I've seen the EditForm component has some built in validation functionality I can expand on. Saving/updating the data will be done using API calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to revisit solution 1 and was able to get the sync working. Here's my code:

```cs
<InputText @bind-Value="Name" />

@code {
  [Parameter] public Person Person { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public EventCallback<Person> PersonChanged { get; set; }

  private Person _Person; // Backing store

  private string Name
  {
    get => _Person.Name;
    set
    {
      if (_Person.Name == value) return;
      _Person.Name = value;
      InvokePersonChanged();
    }
  }

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    _Person = new() {
      Name = Person.Name
    };
  }

  private void InvokePersonChanged()
  {
    if (PersonChanged.HasDelegate) PersonChanged.InvokeAsync(_Person);
  }
}
```